# SharePoint Online: Can't open a CSV File

Tags: sharepoint-online, csv

SharePoint Online with Office 2013

A user was working on a spreadsheet, which was accidently saved as a CSV.  We can't see it in SharePoint either in the browser or via Explorer view but it shows where we'd expect to see it via the Excel "Recent files" info.

Clicking this gives us an error `We can't connect to <<Filepath>>. Please make sure you're using the correct address`

I've checked both site and second stage recycle bin to ensure that this item wasn't accidently deleted but instead it's looking like the file is hidden somehow in SPO.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced a similar instance and if so, how was this resolved?

Comment: the filename doesn't start with an underscore does it?

Comment: Not aw far as I can see, we'e advised users away from that over the course of our work.